# Irreducibility of the polynomial $x^n+5x+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

> This question is first asked by me on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4882302/irreducibility-of-the-polynomial-xn5x3-over-mathbbq), but I haven't recieve a nice answer yet.

I would like to determine whether the polynomial $p(x)=x^n+5x+3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ when $n\ge 2$. Standard criteria (I have tried Eisenstein and $\bmod(p)$ method but both failed) do not seem to apply to this polynomial. I also looked through [this work](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.07568v1), but it seems none of the criteria apply to my situation.

Note: I used Matlab to calculate the circumstance $1<n\le 100$, the result says all of these polynomials are irreducible.

Comment: The irreducibility of $p(x) = x^{n} + 5x + 3$ is equivalent to that of $x^{n} p(1/x) = x^{n} + 5x^{n-1} + 3$, which has been shown on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454756/why-cant-xk5xk-13-be-factored?noredirect=1).

Comment: @JeremyRouse But $x^n p(1/x) =3x^n + 5 x^{n-1}+1$, not the polynomial you claim. For the latter, irreducibility follows straight from Perron's theorem, but not for the former.

Comment: It seems from experimentation that for all $n$ there exists a prime $p\leqslant n^2$ such that $x^n+5x+3$ is irreducible modulo $p$. But I don't yet see a way to predict what $p$ works.

Comment: @DaveBenson Assuming that the Galois group of $f=x^n+5x+3$ is the full symmetric group, then a consequence of Frobenius' denisity theorem would be that $f$ is irreducible modulo $p$ with probability $1/n$. So in fact the expected number of good primes less that $n^2$ would be $n/(2\log n)$ by the prime number theorem.

Comment: True, and that probably always is the Galois group, but there seem to be many values of $n$ for which there is no such $p$ with $p\leqslant n^{5/3}$. For example, $n=5$, $14$, $47$, $58$, $76$, $81$, $95$, $114$, $156$, $158$, $231$, $235$ ...

Comment: At least an infinite class of cases with an easy local argument is given by $n=2^k$ a $2$-power, since then ($f$ mod $5$)$=x^{2^k}-2$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_5$ (indeed, a root generating the field $\mathbb{F}_{5^d}$ would imply the multiplicative order of $5$ modulo $2^{k+2}$ to divide $d$, but this order is always $2^k$).

Comment: @PeterMueller Doesn't the irreducibility of $3x^n+5x^{n-1}+1$ follow immediately from the Rouche-based argument in Jeremy's linked answer? It suffices to show that $3x^n+5x^{n-1}+1$ does not factor over $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. By Rouche's theorem that polynomial has exactly $n-1$ roots inside the unit disc. But then considering the constant terms in an integer-polynomial factorisation means that some product of roots  all $<1$ in absolute value equals $\pm 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: @ThomasBloom: don’t you have to take into account the fact that the polynomial is not monic? In this case, you can only reach a contradiction if the product of the modulus of your roots is less than $1/3$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Some observations. $p(x) = x^n + 5x + 3$ has $n - 1$ roots such that $|x| > 1$ and one real root $x_0 \approx -3/5$. If $p(x) = f(x)g(x)$, $f(0) = 1$, $g(0) = 3$, then $x_0$ is a root of $f$. Based on this, I was able to  prove that $\deg(f) > 0.24n$, $\deg(g) > 0.52n$.

Comment: @ThomasBloom There are lots of reducible trinomials of the form $x^n+ax+b$
 (equivalently $bx^n+ax^{n-1}+1$ when passing to the reciprocal) with $|a|>|b|+1$, showing that there is no analogy with the standard argument ala Rouche / Perron. For example, $x^5-5x+3=(x^2+x-1)(x^3-x^2+2x-3)$, which is embarrassingly similar to the polynomial discussed here.

Comment: Great point, and a very nice example to bear in mind!

Comment: @Aphelli Absolutely, I was missing that the polynomial is not monic, oops, thought that was too easy. I'll leave my comment so others don't make the same mistake.

Comment: I tested (with SageMath) integral polynomials $x^n+ax+b$ for $0<|a|,|b|<20$ and $12\le n\le 300$. Then these are all irreducible polynomials except the obvious exceptions, namely: (a) those with $\pm 1$ as root, (b) those with $\pm j$ as root, with $j$ primitive third root of unity. Namely these in (b) are $x^n+x+1$ for $n=1$ mod $3$, $x^n-x+1$ for $n=5$ mod $6$, $x^n-x+1$ for $n=2$ mod $6$. In degree $8\le n\le 11$ the only exceptions (up to changing $P(x)$ to $(-1)^nP(-x)$) are $x^8+7x-4$, $x^8+3x+14$, $x^9+17x+6$, $x^{11}+12x+8$.

Comment: @YCor Note that for $f$ any monic polynomial of degree $2$, and $n$ any integer $\geq 3$, there exists a unique trinomial $x^n+ax+b$ which is divisible by $f$ and hence irreducible (since every polynomial, including $-x^n$, is congruent mod $f$ to a polynomial of the form $ax+b$). So no irreducibility (up to cyclotomic factors) result is possible without the assumption that $n$ are sufficiently large with respect to $a$ and $b$. However, existing results require $n$ a relatively fast-growing function of $a$ and $b$, while empirics suggest a slow-growing one should do.

Comment: @WillSawin When you say "hence irreducible", you surely meant "hence reducible".

Comment: @GHfromMO Indeed, thanks.

Comment: Overnight bruteforce Maple check verified the statement for $n \leq 3400$ so far...

Comment: @WillSawin yes, I observed this. For instance $x^8+3x+14$ is divisible by $x^2-x-2$, etc. A few of the reducible exceptions still have no factor of degree $1$ or $2$, e.g., $x^8+7x-4$ and $x^{11}+12x+8$ (decomposing 3+5 and 5+6 respectively).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This should be provable using the results of  [On the irreducibility of the non-reciprocal part of polynomials of the form $f(x) x^n+g(x)$](https://huixil.files.wordpress.com/2020/06/on-the-irreducibility-of-the-non-reciprocal-part-of-polynomials-of-the-form-fx-x5en-gx.pdf) by Filaseta-Li-Patane-Skabelund Acta Arithmetica 196 (2020), 187-201 (which builds on my paper "[Irreducibility of polynomials with large gap](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10811)" with Mark Shusterman and Michael Stoll - thanks to GH from MO for pointing out this improved version).

We certainly have irreducibility for all $n \geq 21892$ (which is close to two orders of magnitude from the checked irreducibility for $n\leq 100$.)

The polynomial $x^n+5x+3$ is of the form $f(x) x^n+g(x)$ with $f(x) = 1$ and $g(x)=5x+3$.

Some notation from the paper $\tilde{f}(x) =x^{\deg f} f(x^{-1}) $ and $\| f\|$ is the square root of the sum of the squares of the coefficients of $f$. They also use the Fibonacci sequence $F_n$.

Then $f$ and $g$ satisfy all the criteria of Theorem 2 of the linked paper:

In particular, since $f=1$ and $g$ is irreducible and primitive, $\tilde{f}$ and $g$ are "robust". For $D$ a nonnegative integer $\geq \max(\deg f, \deg g)=2$ and $\kappa$ such that for any polynomials $f_1(x), g_1(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$ where the coefficients of degree $\leq D$ in $f_1(x)$ agree with the coefficients of degree $\leq D$ in $g(x)$ we have $\|f_1 \|^2 + \| g_1\|^2 \geq \kappa$, then if
$$n > D F_{ \|f\|^2 +\|g\|^2 -\kappa + 4} -\deg f$$ and also $n > 3 \deg f + 4 \deg g$ then the non-reciprocal part of $f(x) x^n+ g(x)$ is irreducible.

I will check that (1) the reciprocal part is trivial and (2) we can take $D= 2 $ and $\kappa=17$ which gives irreducibility for $n > 2 F_{21}= 2\cdot 10946= 21892$.

---

(1) Any irreducible reciprocal factor of $x^n+ 5x+3$ must also divide $3 x^n + 5 x^{n-1} + 1$ and thus must divide $(3x +5 ) (x^n+ 5x +3) - x (3x^n+5 x^{n-1}+1) = 15 x^2+ 33 x + 15$ and hence must equal $5 x^2+ 11 x+ 5$ since that polynomial is irreducible. But this clearly can't be a factor for divisibility of the first and last coefficient reasons. So the reciprocal part is trivial and then the whole polynomial is irreducible.

---

(2) Up to sign, one of $f_1,g_1$ must have constant coefficient $1$ and one must have constant coefficient $3$. Wlog $f_1$ has constant coefficient $1$ and $g_1$ has constant coefficient $3$.

Then the coefficients of $x$ in $f_1$ and $f_2$ respectively must equal $ (1,2)$ or $(2,-1)$ - The solutions without the bound on $\|f_1\|^2+\|g_1\|^2 $ form an arithmetic progression, and the next terms $(0,5)$ and $(3,-4)$ have sum of squares at least $25$ which is too large.

In the first case, the coefficients of $x^2$ in $f_1$ and $g_1$ would satisfy $3a + b +2=0$ and in the second case they woudl satisfy $3a+b -2 =0$. In either case this forces $|a|^2+|b|^2\geq 2$. So the sums of squares of the coefficients of $f_1$ and $g_1$ are together at least

$$1^2+3^2+2^2+1^2+2=17$$

justifying $\kappa=17$.

Further work should get slightly higher values of $D$ and smaller values of $\kappa$, giving an improved bound.

Comment: Very nice. I looked up Filaseta-Ford-Konyagin: On an irreducibility theorem of A. Schinzel associated with coverings of the integers (2000), and their Corollary on p.635 tells us that $x^n+5x+3$ is irreducible for $n\geq 2\cdot 5^{137}$. An unspecified but effectively computable sufficient lower bound for $n$ already follows from Theorem 3 in Schinzel: On the reducibility of polynomials and in particular of trinomials (1965).

Comment: The paper Filaseta-Li-Patane-Skabelund: On the irreducibility of the non-reciprocal part of polynomials of the form $f(x)x^n+g(x)$, Acta Arithmetica 196 (2020), 187-201, builds on your paper. Their Corollary 1 gives that $x^n+5x+3$ is irreducible for $n>24157816$.

Comment: @GHfromMO Thanks for pointing that out! Combining that and the calculations already in my answer, I can do a bit better, will do soon.

Comment: This is fun stuff, I did not know about these works and techniques. In particular, I did not know that Erdős covering systems were relevant here. Too bad I am too busy to study this theory. I have already learned a bit, thanks to you.